# Converting time zone date to UTC date

Tags: java, date, time

I have the following date "11.09.2023 00:00:00:000" and I want to convert it to Germany(Berlin) time, and then this Germany(Berlin) time now I want to convert it into UTC time

So "11.09.2023 00:00:00:000" is the current Germany(Berlin) time and since Germany(Berlin) is 2 hours ahead of UTC/GMT time this will mean
the output time should be 10.09.2023 22:00:00:000 in epoch milliseconds. Here is the code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
        test();

    }

    public static void test() throws ParseException {
    //"11.09.2023 00:00:00:000"; via epoch converter is is 1694466000
        Date date1 =Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1694466000));
        ZonedDateTime germanyTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date1.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
        ZoneId utcZone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        ZonedDateTime utcTime = germanyTime.withZoneSameInstant(utcZone);
        long e = utcTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

however the result I get is 10.09.2023 21:00:00:000
I compared the output epoch(1694379600000) in the online unix epoch converters which show   10.09.2023 21:00:00:000 I expect the code to output a long number which when  I convert with online epoch converts to show  10.09.2023 22:00:00:000 GMT/UTC

Comment: Why are you converting to a ZonedDateTime and back again? You're trying to preserve the same instant in time, so anything after `date1.toInstant()` is at best irrelevant. I strongly suspect that the problem is in using `java.util.Date` to start with - your `SimpleDateFormat` is going to use your system default time zone... is that what you want? Is there any reason for using `java.util.Date` at all? I'd personally parse the value as a `LocalDateTime` (as the value itself doesn't provide any more information) then convert *that* into a `ZonedDateTime` by using the right time zone.

Comment: Why are you using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` when you are also already using classes from the `java.time` package?

Comment: I really don't need the SimpleDateFormat, if I could create the Date with 00:00 directly on this day it would be great

Comment: I will change the date to be created without the SimpleDateFormat , but the output is the same

Comment: Move away from `java.util.Date` entirely. It's not helping you. (Note that your claim that the code outputs "10.09.2023 21:00:00:000" is simply not try - the only output from your code is a `long` value, which certainly isn't going to be that...)

Comment: I am always going to receive a Date object with which I should convert it to Germany time and then to UTC time

Comment: @JonSkeet it is outputing 1694466000000 , which in the online epoch converts shows Mon Sep 11 2023 21:00:00 GMT+0000

Comment: "I am always going to receive a Date object" - then you've got a problem, because a Date always represents an instant in time. If that's wrong to start with, that's unhelpful. Your question gives the impression that you actually start with a string. I suggest you read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: `df.format(LocalDateTime.parse(s, df).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")));` Prints *10.09.2023 22:00:00:000* I assume you know how to create `DateTimeFormatter` 'df'. Don't use legacy date classes!

Comment: BTW posted code is just converting `ofEpochSecond` to `toEpochMilli`, that is, multiplying by 1000 (and your epoch converter seems to be off by 1 hour)

Comment: *it is outputing 1694466000000* That’s the same number you put in (only with three more zeroes added because it’s in milliseconds instead of seconds). So what are you surprised about? And yes, that number is equal to Monday 11. September 2023 21:00:00 GMT and to 23:00 Germany/Berlin time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am sorry, this is very unclear and seems confused to me. `"11.09.2023 00:00:00:000"` is a `String`, but you are saying you are receiving an old-fashioned `java.util.Date`? Which is correct? If the end goal is a UTC date and time, why do you want to convert to German time first? And you are printing out a millisecond value that is independent of time zone, but you say you want date and time in UTC. Which is correct? You are probably working way too hard, but neither understanding what you have got nor what you want, I can’t tell you what to do that is simpler.

Comment: And just to make sure we understand each other correctly: Seconds or milliseconds since the epoch give us *a point in time*. So the value is the same no matter from which time zone we see it. There *is no* converting it from from German time to UTC or from any time zone to any other time zone. Because the epoch is one point in time (usually defined in GMT or UTC, but conceptually independent of time zone).

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of your question is about getting UTC from a datetime string in Berlin time. I tested it in [jshell](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jshell/introduction-jshell.html) like the following.

Parse your input, and apply Berlin time zone.

```java
// Get LocalDateTime
jshell> var d1 = LocalDateTime.parse("11.09.2023 00:00:00:000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"))
d1 ==> 2023-09-11T00:00

// Convert d1 to ZonedDateTime of Berlin
jshell> var germanyTime = ZonedDateTime.of(d1, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))
germanyTime ==> 2023-09-11T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Now adjust from Berlin time to UTC (an offset of zero).

```java
// Get instant of germanyTime
jshell> var instant = germanyTime.toInstant()
instant ==> 2023-09-10T22:00:00Z

// Convert it to UTC
jshell> var utcTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
utcTime ==> 2023-09-10T22:00Z[UTC]
```

So you get `2023-09-10T22:00Z[UTC]`, which I suppose what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly parse the date string in the Berlin time zone to ensure that it is being correctly interpreted as your local time:

```java
public static void test() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        Date germanyTime = dateFormat.parse("11.09.2023 00:00:00:000");

        // Convert Berlin time to UTC time
        SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String utcTimeStr = utcFormat.format(germanyTime);
        System.out.println(utcTimeStr);

        // Convert UTC time to epoch milliseconds
        long epochMillis = germanyTime.getTime();
        System.out.println(epochMillis);
    }
```

the  output in my case is :

```
10.09.2023 22:00:00:000
1694383200000
```

without java.util Date and TimeZone and using only java.time:

```
    public static void test() {
        // Parse the date and time directly into a ZonedDateTime in Berlin time
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        ZonedDateTime berlinTime = LocalDateTime.parse("11.09.2023 00:00:00:000", formatter)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
        
        ZonedDateTime utcTime = berlinTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        long epochMillis = utcTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        String utcTimeStr = utcTime.format(formatter);

        System.out.println(utcTimeStr);
        System.out.println(epochMillis);
    }
```

Comment: is a Solution possible where the date is not in a String format but it is directly received as Date object which we need to convert to Germany(Berlin) time

Comment: The types you are using are obsolete, and for good reason. You should not be advising folks to write this kind of code in 2023.

Comment: @Joel I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm trying to stick with his code and answer it as closely as possible, I want to answer the question instead of refactoring the code

Comment: @rzwitserloot I've added the java.time version, You are very welcome to edit the answer and refine it if you want

Comment: @MehdiAkbarianRastaghi Hi, my question was if you had an input a Date object which holds the initial date 00:00:00 , can you transform it to have the same output?

Comment: @Joel that's just not how it works. `Date` objects are a lie; they represent a timestamp without a timezone and thus __do not have__ a seconds and minutes values at all. __They do not represent dates__. Your question might as well be: "I have an Integer containing the value 'Green', can you transform it?" - it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @rzwitserloot isn't it possible somehow to get the timestamp seconds and create a ZoneDate with these seconds that is Germany(Berlin) Time , I know that the date itself it doesn't have information that is from Germany(Berlin) but I know that for sure?

Comment: Sure, @Joel. German time `yourOldfashionedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")))`. Result: `2023-09-11T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]`. UTC is still simpler: `yourOldfashionedDate.toInstant()`. Gives `2023-09-10T22:00:00Z`. The trailing `Z` means UTC.

Comment: @Joel yes, but 'timestamps' are in milliseconds, not seconds, and '0:00:00' does not in any way apply as a concept.